# VIM: Determine if function called from visual-block mode

Tags: vim

From within a function, how can it be determined if the function was called from visual-block mode. This involves calling the function both from:

- normal-mode mapping
- command-line mode

For the precise function, luckily it behaves identically under either normal/command mode or visual-mode with a single line selected. Obviously with more than one line - from `a:firstline/lastline` - the function was not called from normal mode.

The problem now is that I need to know if I am in visual-block mode, single line or not.

I've tried all the following to no avail:

```
function! T() range
    echo [a:firstline, a:lastline]
    echo [getpos("'<")[1:2], getpos("'>")[1:2]]
    echo visualmode()
    echo mode()
endfun
vnoremap TT :call T()<CR>
nnoremap TT :call T()<CR>
```

Output from visual-line mode (notice crazy max-int output):

```
[3, 4]
[[3, 1], [4, 2147483647]]
V
n
```

I require answers of the variety either "can't be done" or "step-by-step". No vague do-this then do-that then finish with this... I'm tired of jumping through obscure VIM Goldberg-esque loopholes just to accomplish simple tasks not provided by any built-in functionality, and honestly my *vim-fu* is still young.

Comment: Can you just pass an addition argument in your key mappings? e.g. `vnoremap TT :call T(1)<CR>` and `nnoremap TT :call T(0)<CR>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just invoke your function like this:

```
vnoremap TT :call T(visualmode())<CR>
nnoremap TT :call T('')<CR>
```

With an empty argument, the function was invoked from normal mode. Else, the passed character represents the visual mode (i.e. `v` vs. `V` vs. `^V`).

Comment: I have no problem with this, but what do I do for commands (for calling from command-line mode)? `command! ... T call T(...)`

Comment: Ex commands always work linewise, like normal mode. You can pass in the range if you define the command like this: `command -range T <line1>,<line2>call T('')`

Comment: So to confirm, that's in the "can't be done" category?

Comment: As I said, commands always work on entire selected lines.  You can't easily determine whether the range supplied to it came from visual mode (i.e. `'<,'>`). But you could have the user pass an argument to indicate that.